# How to present MPMoviePlayerViewController from a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I have a view controller that's been added to a `UITabBarController`. In this view controller I have a button that opens up a movie using `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

When I play the movie, the top navigation bar is still overlayed on top of the movie, effectively blocking out a portion of the screen.

When this view controller isn't inside a `UITabBarController`, however, the movie plays fine.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. I guess things get wonky because `MPMoviePlayerViewController` has a method added as a category to `UIViewController` called `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:`. Normally you would call it like this in your `UIViewController`:

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```

But in this case, if you've added your view controller to a `UITabBarController` stack, `self` is your view controller within the tab bar controller, and I guess this makes things screwy. The fix is to call `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:` with the parent view controller, which in my case, was another `UIViewController` that was housing `UITabBarController`. I simply referenced the parent view and added it to my view controller's `init` method, then called something like `[parentController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp]`.

Whew. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: I'm having this very problem and unfortunately this done not work for me :-\.