# Trouble presenting Modal View Controller (MPMoviePlayerViewController)

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

My App starts up, and I have a UITabBarController.  On the first tab I have a subclass of UIViewController.  It's in this class that I have my movie playing functionality.  I do not know why, but from this class, I cannot presentModalViewController or presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated.  I can however add views as a subView.  I found this post, which is essentially what I'm trying to do (present a movie player view controller): [How to present MPMoviePlayerViewController from a UITabBarController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519133/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-in-a)

But even keeping a reference to the UITabBarController does not work for me.  I'm not really sure why this class has problems presenting a modal view controller, versus in other tabs, I am able to.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more looking, I found that the problem is I cannot present a view modally within the viewDidLoad method.